# Why i need to rebuild project after each update on html or javascript

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

i'v created a solution with more than 30 asp.net pages and it was on each update on html or javascript i just need to do a save on vs 20017 and a browser refresh (firefox).

Now i'v moved all my work to a new solution and vs stopped updating the html and js else if i rebuild the project .

i'v searched a lot on this issue all the answers were about browser caching .. but i don't think it's a browser issue because it was working good with just a refresh on the previous solution ..

I will be thankful if you help me on this , cause rebuilding the solution on each html change is killing me

Comment: which browser using?

Comment: Does your rebuild process result in outputting the website to a different location?  That is, when you're viewing the page in your browser is that the same exact file on the file system as what you're editing in the IDE?

Comment: @HamedJavaheri firefox

Comment: @David yes its the same file